# Why "Bookmarklet for YouTube: Sort videos by length in videos tab" doesn't work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why following bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){l=[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("span.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer"),function(e){l=e.innerHTML.trim().split(":").map(function(t){return parseInt(t)}).reduce(function(p,c){return p*60+c});return{a:e.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement,l:l}}).sort(function(a,b){return a.l-b.l});i=document.querySelector("#primary #items");l.forEach(function(o){i.appendChild(o.a.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)})})()
```

doesn't work the same way in Chrome as it does in Firefox?

In Firefox (69) it works properly, but in Chrome (76) it triggers reloading list of videos.

Warning: It is only meant to be used on videos tabs, i.e. following kind of URLs:

- https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL/videos
- https://www.youtube.com/user/USER/videos

Here you can find beautified version of the code using [Online JavaScript Beautifier](https://beautifier.io/):

```
(function() {
    l = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("span.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer"), function(e) {
        l = e.innerHTML.trim().split(":").map(function(t) {
            return parseInt(t)
        }).reduce(function(p, c) {
            return p * 60 + c
        });
        return {
            a: e.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement,
            l: l
        }
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.l - b.l
    });
    i = document.querySelector("#primary #items");
    l.forEach(function(o) {
        i.appendChild(o.a.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)
    })
})()
```

Comment: I never really root caused the issue and truly understood it, but recently I made a workaround that prevents reloading from happening. I'm removing `<ytd-continuation-item-renderer>` before adding sorted videos and append it later at the end.

See https://gist.github.com/przemoc/533366f71db422652ee8fe5044250470 for current version.